ExchangeService FindItems limitation over time
I have a piece of code that connects to a mailbox via ExchangeService and then search the inbox for any new e-mail every 5 seconds in a while (true) for automated processing. This is working quite well except that once every 66 minutes-ish, when fetching for new e-mails, it throws an exception:
The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
Here is the code that throw the exception:
while (true)
{
    FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(10));
    Thread.Sleep(FrequencyRefresh * 1000);
}

I'm instantiating the ExchangeService with ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1
It seems after 330-ish queries via FindItems the server doesn't allow it.
The timing of 66 minutes + the 5 seconds frequency makes me thinks of kind of limitation in the number of requests per hour but I can't seem to find anything in the documentation about it, only limitation I've seen were about page search but as you can see I'm filtering with ItemView(10) so that's far from the limit of 1000.
After the fail, it connects back 2 min after and continue working.
If anyone can point me in the right direction I'll appreciate it!
Thanks.

Throttling in EWS won't give a 401 it will always be a 500 or 503, you should expect some EWS request to fail for various different reasons and have an inbuilt retry mechanism.  Streaming notifications would also be a better approach then polling every 5 seconds https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-stream-notifications-about-mailbox-events-by-using-ews-in-exchange

maybe try changing your script to the below and it might be worth reading this https://community.spiceworks.com/t/exchange-2016-autodiscover-failure-401-unauthorized-solved/702597/2
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(10));
    }
    catch (ServiceRequestException ex) when (ex.Message.Contains("401"))
    {
        // Re-authenticate
        service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("username", "password");
    }
    Thread.Sleep(FrequencyRefresh * 1000);
}

